# Which software was used to generate this type of map?

Tags: software-recommendations, plot, lambert-conformal-conic

I have been struggling to find the software from which these maps are generated.

[image: Plot1]

[image: Plot2]

[image: Plot3]

[image: Plot4]

It seems like they are created using the same software but I could not find which one. I want to plot variables such as wind speed vectors, mean sea level pressure, and geopotential height on seperate plots that overlay the map of a province in Canada. The types of plot I want are quiver plot and filled contour plot in 2D. The third plot above is the exact type of plot I want for plotting MSL and geopotential height. I am familiar with R and Python and I can produce those plots on rectangular maps (cylindrical projection), but I am not sure if they can produce such plots where the LCC projection is used and the axes are aligned with the boundary of the plot.

Comment: Not sure if such maps are software specific, you can create such types of maps using different software. You should add more information about what exactly you need: what kind of data, what you want to visualize etc.

Comment: Try Generic Mapping Tools (GMT). The last map you showed was generated with Ocean Data View (ODV).